# perl, extract TOC from PDF file

Tags: perl, pdf, tableofcontents

I have checked through CAM::PDF and other PDF related modules, but can not figure if there a way to extract table of content from a clear PDF file.

If there any ideas I would be grateful!

Comment: Have you looked at iText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to find a library that supports the extraction of pdf bookmarks (which is what I assume you mean by table of contents) reliably.

However, [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) does a great job at this and can be run from the command line;

```
pdftk myfile.pdf dump_data | grep BookmarkTitle > outline.txt
```

Comment: Oh, thanks. I actually needed page numbers for each bookmark, but with your example, I figured it out
    pdftk my.pdf dump_data | grep BookmarkPageNumber > 2A_outline.txt